# XML reader and skip certain nodes

Tags: php, xml

After found how to read every XML node and value with XMLreader, i have another problem.

im doing this:

```
    $tablename = 'my_table_name';
    $reader = new XMLReader;
    $reader->xml($MyXml);
    while($reader->read()) {

        if($reader->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {


            if(CheckIFfieldExist($tablename, str_replace(':', '', $reader->name)) == 1){

                $name = str_replace(':', '', $reader->name);
                $reader->read();
                $val = (string)$reader->value;

                    $arrayfield[] = $name;
                    $arrayvalue[] = $val;

                echo $name.' --> '.$val.'<hr>';
            }

        }
    }
```

and work nice, here the function CheckIFfieldExist

```
function CheckIFfieldExist($table, $field){ 
    $var = 0;
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table LIKE '$field'");
    $exists = (mysql_num_rows($result))?TRUE:FALSE;
    if($exists) {$var = 1;}
    return $var;
}
```

here u can see my XML
[xml example](http://codepad.org/1fNDWDba)

i have 2 issues
first i would read only a node called "AttributeSets" and all the nodes inside it

second how can i know when reading ending a node and skip to next?

Answer (score 1):

**First**:
`$reader` also has `name` property: `$reader->name` which holds the name of the node. Check it and do what you need.

**Second**:
There's a special constant `XMLReader::END_ELEMENT`. Check if `$reader->nodeType` equals to it and do what you need. Of course you can use it with checking `name` of the  node.

```
if ($reader->nodeType === XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $reader->name === 'someTag') {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Hello @u_mulder
i tried what u wrote and in some way its work.
But im not satisfy of my code
http://pasted.co/2b2c1e34

i dont know if that is a right way to do what i want...even if work..